# Appropriate classification model for combination of continuous, binary and categorical inputs

Tags: classification, categorical-data, binary-data, continuous-data, artificial-intelligence

I have a binary classification problem for classify my samples to two classes (`class_1` and `class_2`). I have different kinds of inputs: "continuous", "binary" and "categorical". What is the suitable classification method for this combination of inputs? Some of categorical inputs have 10,000 kinds so I can't use coding framework (1, 2, 3, ..., 1/000) for them.

Comment: What sort of variable has 10k categories??? Anyway, my first reaction is to use a tree based method.

Comment: @Andy Blankertz. Thank your for your comment. That is a coding for different types of goods.

Comment: Most methods will have a problem with a categorical variable w/ 10k levels. You may want to see if you can group them into a smaller number of coherent levels, either by theoretical knowledge (eg `tomato soup` & `chicken noodle soup` -> `soup`) or by clustering the levels.